How to fx? ipython encounters "Unhandled exception in event loop" when I move the anaconda prompt
Usually when I first move the anaconda prompt to the the right half of the screen by pressing Windows key + Right arrow,
then I run ipython,
everything goes well.
but earlier this week, I tried to run ipython before moving the anaconda prompt to the the right half of the screen
it shows "Unhandled exception in event loop" after moving the anaconda prompt to the the right half of the screen

Exception
Unhandled exception in event loop:
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\application.py", line 1026, in in_term
    await _do_wait_for_enter("Press ENTER to continue...")

  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\application.py", line 1545, in _do_wait_for_enter
    await session.app.run_async()

  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\application.py", line 886, in run_async
    return await _run_async(f)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\application.py", line 739, in _run_async
    self._redraw()

  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\application.py", line 543, in _redraw
    self.context.copy().run(run_in_context)

  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\application.py", line 526, in run_in_context
    self.renderer.render(self, self.layout)

  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\renderer.py", line 678, in render
    WritePosition(xpos=0, ypos=0, width=size.columns, height=height),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\layout\screen.py", line 314, in __init__
    assert width >= 0


What's the question? Do you want to ask why the error is occurring, or how to fix it, or both, or something else? Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask].

@wjandrea
Yes. I cannot resolve this issue and would like to know how to fix it. thanks
